# php tcp socket listener data parse

Tags: php, sockets, gps, tracker

I have gps tracker which is sending data to my server over tcp and my server has been coded in PHP. the device is sending data in every 5 seconds. The issue is that the first response comes fine as soon as socket established connection with the client but then subsequent responses comes in weird characters and no idea of how to interpret them.

**Server.php** code
[SocketServer.class.php](https://github.com/ScottPhillips/PHP-TCP-Port-Listener/blob/master/SocketServer.class.php)

```
<?php

require_once("SocketServer.class.php"); 
$server = new SocketServer("172.xx.xx.xxx",8000); 
$server->max_clients = 10; 
$server->hook("CONNECT","handle_connect"); // Run handle_connect every time someone connects
$server->hook("INPUT","handle_input"); 
$server->infinite_loop(); 


function handle_connect(&$server,&$client,$input) {
    SocketServer::socket_write_smart($client->socket,"String? ","");
}


function handle_input(&$server,&$client,$input) {
  
    $trim = trim($input); 

    if(strtolower($trim) == "quit") 
    {
        SocketServer::socket_write_smart($client->socket,"Oh... Goodbye..."); 
        $server->disconnect($client->server_clients_index); // Disconnect this client.
        return; 
    }

    $output = strrev($trim); 

    SocketServer::socket_write_smart($client->socket,$output); 
    SocketServer::socket_write_smart($client->socket,"String? ",""); 
}
```

Output:

```
Triggering Hook 'handle_connect' for 'CONNECT'
*HQ,9176952312,V6,115939,V,3127.2665,N,07307.6974,E,0.00,126.00,100822,FFF7FBFF,410,1,325,14688,8992300001243970980F,#

Triggering Hook 'handle_input' for 'INPUT'
0@119.160.59.240 --> $?v?#uY"1'&e0v?
                                    &????ʧ?E9`,
Triggering Hook 'handle_input' for 'INPUT'
0@119.160.59.240 --> $?v?#uY"1'&e0v?
                                    &????ʧ?E9`,
```

**hex dump** if data comes correctly

```
<Buffer 2a 48 51 2c 39 31 37 36 39 35 32 33 37 35 2c 56 36 2c 31 35 35 37 32 32 2c 56 2c 33 31 32 37 2e 33 30 33 34 2c 4e 2c 37 33 30 37 2e 36 36 33 36 2c 45 ... 65 more bytes>
```

**Hex dump** incorrect response

```
24 91 76 95 23 75 15 57 24 10 08 22 31 27 30 34 04 07 30 76 63 0c 00 00 00 ff f7 fb ff 00 01 c7 f0 00 00 00 00 01 9a 01 01 45 7f 2d 00
```

Comment: Instead of printing characters, could you print the hex dump? That might be easier to read and debug

Comment: Nothing in this program prints anything, where does the output come from?

Comment: as to the format, you have the documentation for the gps device where that format must be explained, not us.

Comment: How come the first input line doesn't print the IP address?

Comment: @BarryCarter I have updated my question. Please check

Comment: @user253751 Please check socket.server.php class. I have attached the link

Comment: All the code related to the question needs to be in the question. And please remove all the code that is not necessary. E.g. are these hooks really related to the problem, or is the problem still there when you just print the received data, instead of using the hooks? (There's a 50% chance that when you remove all the unneeded code you'll accidentally discover the answer yourself)

Comment: @user253751 I have intentionally removed it from here as it was irrelevant

Comment: why do you think it's irrelevant? Is SocketServer a standard class that everyone else is using? I thought it was something you wrote

Comment: @user253751 well that is not the problem because same tracker I tested in my node js code as well and the same response is coming when using different code and language so certainly I am 100% sure its not the problem with the code. I guess I might need to parse it differently which I don't know

Comment: @user253751 Its standard library. I attached the link from where I took it

Comment: Okay, you probably should have mentioned you get the same thing with node.js. That means it's probably not a problem with your code - this is just the data the tracker is sending.

Comment: the hex dump shows the first response (the one that's ok) but not any of the others

Comment: @user253751 I have attached the hex of incorrect data as well

Comment: @user253751 yeah true. sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: Do you have documentation for the GPS tracker telling you what it's supposed to send?

Comment: @user253751 this is the device I am using https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/smart-gps-tracker-ST-901A_60234277646.html